# Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_212\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'

Tags: java, windows

Устанавливал jdk 12 и 8, потом удалил 8, но система запомнила только путь к 8.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было просто удалить все предыдущие версии явы в `Параметры -> Установка и удаление программ`.

Answer (score 1):

В переменных окружения надо задать/изменить переменную с именем `JAVA_HOME`, в которой будет путь до папки с JDK нужной версии. Далее в переменную `PATH` добавить строку вида `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`. И думаю счастье настанет.

Comment: Нет, у меня это уже было добавлено, и оно нужно для javac.